# Kill Mysql service running on any port, Mac Sierra

Tags: mysql, service

Kill Mysql service running on any port using terminal. 
Port number like 3306 or any.

Answer (score 15):

`sudo pkill mysql` should serve your purpose.

If for some reason `mysqld` survives this, `sudo pkill mysqld` as well.

More information from SuperUser:
https://superuser.com/questions/983969/how-to-kill-mysql-with-moving-pid

Comment: This works perfectly. Initially used `sudo kill -9 <PID>` but MySQL gets assigned another Process Identification Number instead. After using the suggestion above, when you run `sudo lsof -i :3306` to check for processes running on port 3306, you should see nothing.

Answer (score 8):

Simplifying your answer.

1) Go to Launchpad Type Terminal then Run this.

2) Run following commands

Check if Mysql service is running

For all listening ports

## netstat -vanp tcp

Apply port filter

## netstat -vanp tcp | grep

## netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3306

Kill Mysql Service

## sudo pkill mysql

## or 
 sudo pkill mysqld

< Enter password >

## Done !!!

Answer (score 0):

Run this in terminal:

lsof -n -iTCP:3306 -sTCP:LISTEN -n -l -P | grep 'LISTEN' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9